# How to restrict serverside validations till completion of client side validations jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax request for serverside validations at the same time i am using client side validations using jquery validate but i am getting both the validations at a time i want to restrict server side validation till client side validation is complete

my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userForm").validate({
        rules: {
           firstName: "required",
           lastName: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            firstName: "FirstName is required",
            lastName: "LastName is required",
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            // error.insertAfter("#some");
            error.insertAfter(element.siblings("span"));
        }
    });
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    $("form").valid();
});

});
function validateAddUser(){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "validateAddNewUser.php",                  
           data: $("#userForm").serialize(),
           success: function(msg){
               if(msg)
               {
                   $('#messageConatiner').html(msg);
               }
               else
               {
                   $('#messageConatiner').html(msg);
               }
           }   
     });
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="messageConatiner"></div>
<div id="formtb">
<form action="validateAddNewUser.php" method="POST" id="userForm">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="1"
    class="tabcont">
    <tr>
        <td width="47%" align="right">
            *First Name:
        </td>
        <td width="53%">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstName"/>
            <br />
            <span></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            * Last Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastName"/>
            <br />
            <span></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2">
            <input name="addNewUser" type="button" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateAddUser();" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the `validate()` function have a callback when it completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your `validateAddUser()` function in: (and remove it from `onclick`)

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { 
        validateAddUser();
    }
});
```

Comment: it is not working i have removed onclick function in document.ready state i have copied this code...

Comment: after the values entered also it is not calling that function

Comment: Can you give me the link of the jQ plugin?

Answer (score 0):

```
return false;
```

in errorPlacement after inserting the error msg in span tag. In this way if validation does not false on client side it stops the default behaviour of click event.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if($("form").valid()){    $("#submit").click();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
$(function () {
$(form).validate(); $(form).submit(function () {" enter code here" }); });
```